# How to Design a Restful API for a Bulk Save?

Tags: c#, rest

In my RESTful Web API application, I am using the below templates at the moment:

```
Get one product by id: 
GET api/product/12

Save product
POST api/product

Update product
PUT api/product
```

What is the best uri template for bulk post?

My inital thought is this:

```
POST api/product/bulk
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
 RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

void SaveProduct(int productId);
```

suppose that, you have the following service with proper implementation. for this, your service uri will be :

yourDomain/SaveProduct/productId=productIdNumber

Answer (score 2):

I find this more intuitive:

```
POST api/products
```

Comment: But like I said, I already have this for a single POST. Can they coexist?!